# Smallest positive number in a base-2 floating point system

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754

Consider a floating point number system which has base=2, precision=3, lower exponent limit L=-1 and Upper exponent limit (U)=1

What is the smallest positive number that can be represented?

My answer is 0.01 * 2^-1 = 0.001 in base 2 = 0.125 in base 10

But the answer is apparently 1.00 * 2 ^-1 = 0.1 in base 2 = 0.5 in base 10

Can someone please explain?

Note: I am aware that there is a formula to determine the smallest positive integer which is (base ^ (lower exponent limit)) which also gives 0.5, but I would like to know why my answer is incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ambiguity because the floating-point number system is not clearly specified. With the information given, we cannot state definitively which answer is correct.

Floating-point systems common require a non-zero leading digit for most numbers. For example, IEEE 754 requires the first bit of the significand to be (implicitly) 1 for “normal” binary floating-point numbers. However, it also has “subnormal” numbers, in which the first bit is 0.

The answer you show as correct, apparently according to some authority (a teacher who wrote a test?), uses a normalized significand, 1.00. The answer you suggested uses an unnormalized significand, 0.01. To say which is correct, we need to know whether the floating-point system in question allows unnormalized significands or not.